# Manager can auto-follow cases and tasks of their subordinate in Chatter

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, criteria

Chatter only provides feature to auto-follow based on ownership.

I have a requirement that manager should auto-follow cases and tasks of agents that falls under their hierarchy of role. eg manager-subordinate.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [good Appexchange product](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GGRwEAO) which you can try if fulfills your requirement.
Or you can write some trigger to autofollow.

```
//Logic to see if logged in User reports to Manager
EntitySubscription es = new EntitySubscription();
es.ParentId = aid;
es.SubscriberId = "<Managers User Id>" ;
insert es ;
```